# Теряется кодировка русских символов при обработке строк

Tags: golang

```
a:="аюв"
fmt.Println(a) //Вернет аюв
fmt.Println(a[1:2]) //Вернет знак вопроса в ромбике
b:=a[1:2]
fmt.Println(b) //Вернет знак вопроса в ромбике
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a:="аюв"

fmt.Println(len([]rune(a))) // 3
fmt.Println(len(a))         // 6

fmt.Println(a) //Вернет аюв
fmt.Println(a[2:4]) // ю
b:=a[2:4]
fmt.Println(b) // ю
```

В документации данное поведение детально описано [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

"Оператор индекса, применяемый к строке, возвращает байтовое значение (byte value), а не символ (как в других языках)." by [50 оттенков Go](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/314804/)

Answer (score 2):

string в go это неизменяемая последовательность байтов.

```
a := "аюв" // 3 символа кириллицы в кодировке utf-8 занимают 6 байт. По 2 байта на каждый символ.
fmt.Println(len(a)) // Выведет 6, поскольку len возвращает число байтов в строке.
```

Операция индексирования возвращает указанный байт строки

```
for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%#x ", a[i])
}
```

Выведет коды всех шести байтов:

```
0xd0 0xb0 0xd1 0x8e 0xd0 0xb2
```

Операция получения подстроки a[i:j] дает новую строку, состоящую из байтов исходной строки, начиная с индекса i и до (но не включая) байта с индексом j.

```
fmt.Println(a[1:2]) // В функцию Println будет передан string состоящий из единственного байта - 0xb0. Второй байт из строки a.
```

Println попытается декодировать этот string в последовательность rune с помощью кодировки utf-8, но так как единственный байт 0xb0 не является валидной строкой utf-8, то для него будет сгенерирован так называемый [заменяющий символ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB) имеющий код 0xfffd (знак вопроса в ромбике).

Answer (score 1):

Строки работают с байтами, а вам нужен слайс из рун.

```
a := "аюв"
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(string([]rune(a)[1:2]))
```

[Напечатает "ю" как вы хотите.](https://play.golang.org/p/yFHoL0ELCl)

Один из авторов Go по совместительству [автор UTF-8](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/utf-8-history.txt), потому поддержка всевозможные юникодных строк в Go просто превосходная.